# How to extract TD values only with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am extracting the forexfactory calendar. I can do a `puts` of the `td` values but it's printing the full HTML tags. How do I get the `td` value of a tag with class "calendar__time"?

My code is:

```
require 'HTTParty' 
require 'Nokogiri' 
require 'Pry' 
require 'csv' 

page = HTTParty.get('http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=aug31.2016') 
p= Nokogiri::HTML(page) 
rows=p.css('tr.calendar_row')
rows.map do |row|

  puts row.css('td.calendar__date')
    puts row.css('td.calendar__time')
end
```

When I check with irb, it's returning it with the tags:

```
     <td class="calendar__cell calendar__time time">9:45pm</td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="calendarexpanded__graph" data-touchable><span>Graph</span></a> </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
    <td class="calendar__cell calendar__date date"></td>
```

The HTML snippet for this TR is:

```
<tr class="calendar__row calendar_row calendar__row--grey " data-eventid="62529" data-touchable>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__date date"></td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__time time">2:00am</td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__currency currency">CHF</td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__impact impact calendar__impact calendar__impact--low">
      <div class="calendar__impact-icon calendar__impact-icon--screen"> <span title="Low Impact Expected" class="low"></span> </div>
      <div class="calendar__impact-icon calendar__impact-icon--print"> <img src="resources/images/icons/impact/impact-yellow.png" alt="" border="0" /> </div>
   </td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__event event">
      <div> <span class="calendar__event-title">UBS Consumption Indicator</span> </div>
   </td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__detail detail"><a class="calendar__detail-link calendar__detail-link--level-1 calendar_detail level1" data-level="1"></a></td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__actual actual">1.32</td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__forecast forecast"></td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__previous previous"><span class="revised worse" title="Revised From 1.34">1.21</span></td>
   <td class="calendar__cell calendar__graph graph"><a class="calendar__detail-link calendar__detail-link--graph-icon calendar_chart"></a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="calendar__row calendar__expand  " data-eventid="62529">
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td colspan="4" class="calendarexpanded__container">
      <table class="calendarexpanded">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="calendarexpanded__cell"><strong>Actual</strong>1.32</td>
               <td class="calendarexpanded__cell"><strong>Forecast</strong>&nbsp;</td>
               <td class="calendarexpanded__cell"><strong>Previous</strong><span class="revised worse" title="Revised From 1.34">1.21</span></td>
               <td class="calendarexpanded__cell calendarexpanded__cell--small"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="calendarexpanded__details calendarexpanded__details--1" data-touchable><span>Details</span></a> </td>
               <td class="calendarexpanded__cell calendarexpanded__cell--small">
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with code it's important to provide the minimal input data necessary to duplicate the problem. Your input HTML isn't valid, which would make Nokogiri do fixups, which can totally alter the DOM after parsing, causing selectors to fail or misfire in comparison to the original/syntactically correct HTML. Also, don't use `map` when all you are doing is printing inside the block. Instead you should use `each`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing as follows:

```
puts row.css('td.calendar__date').text
```